# SSRS 2012 Data Driven Subscriptions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am doing a data driven subscription, (e-mail) . I have  expression(Value) in the report  which  varies depending upon the parameters selected. Can we include a report expression(value) output in the email body along with the HTML text ? Is this possible?

Any work around?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are referring to the "Comment" field that you define when creating the data driven subscription then the only parameters that seem to be available are @ReportName and @ExecutionTime. The subscription is not aware of the data driven command results :(